# Bootstrap 4 tooltip container right after element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I would like to place my appearing tooltips right after the .form-group tag. So outside, not inside it as I managed so far.

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYveRq

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group input-group-lg d-flex">
    <input class="form-control col-11" type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Focussed text field with floating label">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is some tooltip content that appears on hover of question mark. This is some tooltip content that appears on click of question mark." class="help-icon align-self-end ml-auto">?</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function () {
    $(this).tooltip({
        trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        container: $(this).parent('.form-group')
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want it to be outside as in [Bootstrap's Examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#examples)? Or in a whole new `div` that you can manipulate?

Comment: The actual tooltip div with .tooltip class should appear after .form-group div. In the codepen example is almost good, but it's inside the .form-group div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your .form-group in container and change "container" in your function

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
    <div class="form-group input-group-lg d-flex">
      <input class="form-control col-11" type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Focussed text field with floating label">
      <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is some tooltip content that appears on hover of question mark. This is some tooltip content that appears on click of question mark." class="help-icon align-self-end ml-auto">?</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
    <div class="form-group input-group-lg d-flex">
      <input class="form-control col-11" type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Focussed text field with floating label">
      <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is some tooltip content that appears on hover of question mark. This is some tooltip content that appears on click of question mark." class="help-icon align-self-end ml-auto">?</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function () {
  $(this).tooltip({
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    container: $(this).closest('.tooltip-wrapper')
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks you @ArtemGoldsmith

Comment: seems simple enough what versions are you using popper and bs and not matter what i try it does not work..

Comment: ok i was having an issue where jquery-ui was overrideing bootstrap..